# Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datetimepicker'.. Can't seem to create a datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

Always getting an error whenever I try to create a datepicker in my form. Can anyone help me out? I believed I have referenced the proper CSS, JS, Bootstrap and JQuery files.

```
 <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/color2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/font_google.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrapValidator.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/PageValidator.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Validator2.js"></script>

    <link href="css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

here's my attempt at creating a datepicker

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Birthday">Birth Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon flat">
            <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
        <div class="input-group date" id="dobPicker" data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="birthday" name="birthday" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
              data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="Birth Date is required and cannot be empty"
              data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY" data-bv-date-message="Invalid Date" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('#birthday').datetimepicker({
             pickTime: false
         });
     });
    </script>
```

Any insight (and possibly a code fix) would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Usually in this case it is a scripts issue that is not referenced correctly. Just check if your browser referenced it in your source code

Answer (score 2):

I know i am 2 years late to the party, but i just had the problem and found 'a' solution that might help someone in the future.

I got an error of undefined method because i loaded the wrong .js file out of the bundle. 
I loaded `jquery.datetimepicker.min.js` out of the `root` dir from the package instead of `jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js` out of the `build` folder.

Answer (score 1):

If its bootstrap date Time picker use the following code :

```
 $(function () {
      $('#birthday').datepicker()({
         pickTime: false
       });
  });
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QD94K/1/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case I fixed it by adding:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [this](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) datepicker, you should select the containing `div` instead of the input element.

```
$(function () {
    $('#dobPicker').datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add - jquery_calendar/jquery-ui.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery_calendar/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
```

then add JQuery code

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.openCalendar').datepicker({
        closeText: "Select",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });});
```

if Jquery Ui is not there Calander will not works.